# How can I directly update the join model in a has_many_through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails app with two models, joined by a third:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :shopping_list_items
    has_many :users, through: :shopping_list_items
end


class ShoppingListItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :food
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shopping_list_items
  has_many :foods, through: :shopping_list_items
end
```

The middle model, `ShoppingListItem`, has a few extra attributes, including `priority` which I'd like to update directly.

So for instance, I'd like to do something like:

```
r = current_user.shopping_list_items.where(food_id: 1).first
r.priority = "urgent"
r.save
```

The object looks fine until I try to save it, **when I get a SQL error:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...$1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "shopping_list_items"."" IS NULL
                                                             ^
: UPDATE "shopping_list_items" SET "priority" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "shopping_list_items"."" IS NULL):
```

I guess it's complaining about the absence of a primary key? Not sure how to fix this, since the rails docs say that join tables shouldn't have a primary key column...

I created the middle table with a migration like this, :

```
   create_table :shopping_list_items, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :food

      t.string :priority
      t.integer :position

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Comment: In this case, shopping_list_items is not a join table in the way the rails docs mean.  Add an id column to your table and all this should work.

Comment: Because you are using a `has_many thorough association` and can update the through model to store additional data you should have an primary_key in it.